# aChartEngine performance and memory usage

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I need to write some graph for an android application. I've try GraphView libraries but it doesn't satisfy me, there's still a lot of bug. 
The main on it's for zooming and scrolling: After zooming in i can't zoom out and scroll.
I need a library easy to use, and lightweight because for my use case, i need to keep 3 graph in memory until the app is in foreground, and dynamic add values to graph during execution.
AChartEngine could be ok for my purpose?

Comment: Out of curiosity - what did you choose?

Comment: i've choose aChartEngine

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is very dependent on what FITS you best and not what IS THE BEST. I've done some research about charts not long ago, I can share my thoughts. 
I found [aFreeChart](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) to fit best.

Aspects that I would consider (and remarks on aFreeChart):

- License of code (aFreeChart is LGPL, not the typical apache)
- Documentation (a lot of the derived work is based on the very well documented **j**FreeChart)
- Popularity (aFreeChart not that popular, but jFreeChart is very popular and you can find a lot of Q&A for it online)
- Is the Source editable for your needs (YES)
- And of course, Basic features (Zoom & pan, huge amount of chart types)
- Performance (I've found the library to be very efficient. you can check the demo I think it offers test of more than 1 chart at a time)

Comment: sure, i've asked for wich one fits my best (i've write my use case :) ). Now i'm trying AChartEngine, then i try aFreeChart too and look at the differences